# Angular Google Maps - Two-way data binding in map-control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm having trouble making a map-controller with Angular's two-way data binding expressions:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="control.tpl.html">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-class="{'btn-warning': danger}" ng-click="controlClick()"><h1>{{controlText}}</h1></button>
</script>

<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
    <ui-gmap-map-control template="control.tpl.html" position="center" controller="controlCtrl" index="-1"></ui-gmap-map-control>
</ui-gmap-google-map>

<div ng-controller="controlCtrl">
    <h1>{{controlText}}</h1>
    <label>Two-way Data Binding:</label>
    <input ng-model="controlText">
</div>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7hCEQBMFYQeirAmOSrhX?p=preview) with my problem.

Is there a way to change the binded attribute in the map-control?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change the bound attribute in the map-control:

1) introduce a separate controller for the template to share its scope with another controller:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="control.tpl.html">
    <div ng-controller="templateCtrl">
       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-class="{'btn-warning': danger}" ng-click="controlClick()"><h1>{{controlText}}</h1></button>
    </div>   
</script>
```

2) Broadcast changes:

```
$scope.$watch('controlText', function () {
         $rootScope.$broadcast('controlText:changed', $scope.controlText);
});
```

3) Receive changes in template controller:

```
.controller('templateCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('controlText:changed', function(event, val) {
       $scope.controlText = val;
    }); 
})
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EjXW0wJizDfBKgJ44I8k?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, why do we need to create a separate controller? It's like the map-control creates a new instance of the controller we pass to it.

Comment: The reason of creating a controller inside a template  is to share the same scope between controller(s) and a template